# Why argument like q not mentioned in vim manual?

Tags: linux, vim

I know  :q comman  q! is use to exit from a file without shaving any changes.So I was expecting this to be documented in manual of vim but did not find any

When I tried to  search vim manual for q command  `man vim | grep q`  i got below which is different from quit

> vim [options] -q [errorfile]    -q [errorfile]
> Start  in  quickFix  mode.   The file [errorfile] is read and the first error is displayed.  If [errorfile] is omitted, the
> filename is obtained
> ":cn" command.  See ":help quickfix".

so why vim argument like `q` is not mentioned in vim manual. Learning linux , just wanted to ensure not missing anything here ?

Comment: [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation)

Comment: All the answers critical of your question aside, I do think you have a valid point; something as fundamental as **quitting** an interactive application should be mentioned in the manual page. And any reference to `:help :q` implies that you already **know** that you have to look for `:q`.  That said: this isn't really a question/comment for stackoverflow, but rather for the vim maintainers. And there's a good chance this has been previously raised (and discarded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, Vim has an online help manual to which you can navigate with `:help TOPIC`.  In your case, that would be `:help :q`.

The reason you didn't find this in the manual page is that Vim has a large number of commands, options, and features, and the manual page would be very large.  Even the POSIX manual page of vi is rather extensive, and it is much less featureful.  Searching in a manual page is also more difficult than the built-in help system is.

Answer (score 3):

`:q` is a "command", not an "argument".

> just wanted to ensure not missing anything here

Well, you missed the following section of `$ man vim`:

```
ON-LINE HELP
   Type ":help" in Vim to get started.  Type ":help subject" to get help on a
   specific  subject.   For example: ":help ZZ" to get help for the "ZZ" com-
   mand.  Use <Tab> and CTRL-D to complete subjects  (":help  cmdline-comple-
   tion").   Tags  are  present  to  jump  from one place to another (sort of
   hypertext links, see ":help").  All documentation files can be  viewed  in
   this way, for example ":help syntax.txt".
```

Which should have led you to try `:help :q` in Vim.

When you are learning, you don't `grep` manuals, your *read* them.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has built-in manual, `:help`(or `:h`) ex command.
Just do `:h :q` and you'll get the doc for `:quit` command.